# Can't create ragged array if there is a matching dimension (python/numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm doing like this:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.zeros((12,2))
>>> B = np.zeros((12,))
>>> A
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
>>> B
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> C = np.array([A, B], dtype=object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (12,2) into shape (12)
```

It get an error. But when I do like this:

```py
>>> A = np.zeros((20,2))
>>> B = np.zeros((12,))
>>> C = np.array([A, B], dtype=object)
>>> C
array([array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]]),
       array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
      dtype=object)
```

It doesn't complain.

Why? How do I store two arrays when they have dimensions like `(12,2)` and `(12,)`?

Comment: `np.hstack([A,B[...,None]])`?

Comment: Making a "ragged" array with `np.array` is inherently iffy.  The primary "goal" of this function is to make a multidimensional numeric array.  As the `futurewarning` tells us making a 'ragged array' is a fallback option.  And as you found even that can fail - when the leading dimensions match.

Comment: To be safe I recommend making a `c=np.empty(2, object)` and assigning `A` and `B` to their respective terms.  That works regardless of the mix of shapes, even two identical shapes.